# How to create custom char ID field in Odoo model?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

In odoo id special field is allways an auto incremental integer. But for my Odoo app I want that field (id) to be a Char for an specific model. That id will also be use for Many2One relations. How can I do that? I am working with Odoo 14

Comment: Odoo will override any [id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/models.py#L449) field when setting up the model

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend manipulating the id field. Instead, I'd suggest you add another char field and then you can use the `_sql_constraints` attribute on your model. Let's say, for example, your unique Char field is *city*, you can use the following example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    city = fields.Char(string='City', related='related.model', readonly=False)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('check_city_unique', 'UNIQUE(city)', 'The city is not unique')
    ]
```

***`_sql_constraints`*** accepts three arguments:

- A unique name for the argument
- The constraint. In this example we've used unique, but you can use any sql constraint. I use **CHECK** a lot in odoo. You can learn more about SQL Constraints here: [You can learn more about SQL Constraints here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp)
- An error message when the constraint fails.

You can also find more about constrains on [odoo's developer docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/11_constraints.html)

Good luck!